# Add to home screen' Web App Install Banner not showing up in my web app and showing error

Tags: html, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

Below is the my manifest.json file

```
{
    "short_name": "ponds.brandfans.co",
    "name": "ponds.brandfans.co",
    "icons": [{
        "src": "/images/logo/favicons/36x36.png",
        "sizes": "36x36",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": "0.75"
    }, {
        "src": "/images/logo/favicons/36x36.png",
        "sizes": "48x48",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": "1.0"
    }, {
        "src": "/images/logo/favicons/36x36.png",
        "sizes": "72x72",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": "1.5"
    }, {
        "src": "/images/logo/favicons/36x36.png",
        "sizes": "96x96",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": "2.0"
    }, {
        "src": "/images/logo/favicons/36x36.png",
        "sizes": "144x144",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": "3.0"
    }, {
        "src": "/images/logo/favicons/36x36.png",
        "sizes": "192x192",
        "type": "image/png",
        "density": "4.0"
    }],
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "gcm_sender_id": "482941778795",
    "background_color": "#2c3e50",
    "theme_color": "#2c3e50"
}
```

I am getting an error: "Site cannot be installed: the page does not work offline"
Please let me know if I missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

Funny you asked this question. I was rendering a video that answers this question :)
https://youtu.be/xvLnmdjgEWY

Your serviceworker needs a fetch event handler.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I also wrote a blog post - https://love2dev.com/blog/is-your-progressive-web-app-may-not-prompting-the-customer-to-add-to-home-screen/

Answer (score 0):

As seen in Chris Love's blog and video, you must add this to your service worker javascript code:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {});
```

(For me the service worker file (sw.js) only contains this line)